# GLM with a Poisson distribution, how to conduct a post-hoc test?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, biostatistics

I have a dataset in which I compare the total number (the summed number of birds over a couple of weeks) of birds across different distances (continuous factor). I hypothesize that the numbers of birds is the highest at the first distance and declines. The model I used was a GLM.

I  now have a significant effect of the Distance, which is what I was expecting. But what can I use to see which of the distances differ from each other? I've tried this but that didn't work.

```
post1 <- glht(m5, family = poisson())
summary(m5, test = adjusted())
```

The emmeans package does not work.

This question can be deleted, the answer did not work and I did not conduct a post-hoc.

Comment: What do you mean by a "continuous factor"? Is the variable numeric (continuous) or a factor (categorical)?

Comment: Please don't erase questions, at least not by overwriting them.  If you really want to, you can delete the question.  If you found a workable solution to your problem, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want the `emmeans` package. It is remarkably broad and effective. Below, I simulate data that might look like yours. Then I calculate all pairwise comparisons and then just the contrast of interest that you are interested in.

```
# generate fake data that might look like what you want ------------------------
set.seed(1839) # for replicability
n <- 400 # sample size
Distance <- factor(sample(1:5, n, TRUE)) # make distance from 1 to 5 and factor
# make rain and method covariates that are unrelated to outcome: 
Rain <- rbeta(400, 4, 2)
Method <- rbinom(n, 1, .4)
# calculate number that distance 1 is higher than the other 4:
Number <- rpois(n, ifelse(Distance == "1", 4, 2))

# fit model --------------------------------------------------------------------
model <- glm(Number ~ Distance + Rain + Method, family = "poisson")

# use emmeans ------------------------------------------------------------------
library(emmeans)
# all post-hoc comparisons:
pairs(emmeans(model, ~ Distance))

# just the contrast you wanted:
contrast(emmeans(model, ~ Distance), method = "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = 1)
# see ?contrast-methods for more information on types of methods of contrasts
# as well as how to specify the reference (that is, it should be the level value
# and not the label)
```

There are tons of great vignettes to help learn `emmeans`, e.g.:

- Comparisons and contrasts https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html
- Models supported by `emmeans` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html
- Sophisticated models in `emmeans` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html
- Basics https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html
- Interactions https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html

Comment: This question looks entirely off topic--ie, only about code & packages. What saves it is the OP's apparent confusion about some of the underlying statistical concepts (eg, about continuous vs factor variables, about how `distance` as used in the formula relates to the idea that distance 1 might differ from the others, but the others not differ w/i themselves, etc). Can you address any of that in your answer?